# How to change html attribute value with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have select tag of HTML I want to change `/id/` with help jquery in `data-ajax--url` attribute

```
<select data-ajax--url="/live_search/Customer/id/name/name" class="form-control kt-select2 kt-live_search form-control-md" id="consignments_customername" data-placeholder="All">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, can you explain more precisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**NOTE** Your attribute name is invalid.

```js
$(function() {
  const $sel =  $("#consignments_customername");
  const dataurl = $sel.attr("data-ajax--url");
  $sel.attr("data-ajax--url",dataurl.replace(/\/id\//,"/help/"));
  console.log($sel.attr("data-ajax--url"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-ajax--url="/live_search/Customer/id/name/name" class="form-control kt-select2 kt-live_search form-control-md" id="consignments_customername" data-placeholder="All">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

If you change the `--` to an underscore, you could do this in plain JS

```js
window.addEventListener("load",() => {
  const sel =  document.getElementById("consignments_customername");
  const dataurl = sel.dataset.ajax_url;
  sel.dataset.ajax_url = dataurl.replace(/\/id\//,"/help/");
  console.log(sel.dataset.ajax_url);
})
```

```html
<select data-ajax_url="/live_search/Customer/id/name/name" class="form-control kt-select2 kt-live_search form-control-md" id="consignments_customername" data-placeholder="All">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this - simple plain vanilla js will do it.

First -use querySelector to get the selecto list via its id, then get the data-attribute via getAttribute()... modifiy it be replace() - or you could split th string and rejoin it - then set the  new string as the data-attibute via setAttribute().

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#consignments_customername');

const newURL = el.getAttribute('data-ajax--url').replace(/\/id\//,'/help/');

el.setAttribute('data-ajax--url', newURL);

console.log(el); //shows the newURL has been applied to the data-attribute
```

```html
<select data-ajax--url="/live_search/Customer/id/name/name" class="form-control kt-select2 kt-live_search form-control-md" id="consignments_customername" data-placeholder="All">
  <option>option 1</option>
</select>
```

If you wanted to do this with split() and join() then its almost the same code

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#consignments_customername');

const newURL = el.getAttribute('data-ajax--url').split('/id/').join('/help/');

el.setAttribute('data-ajax--url', newURL);

console.log(el); //shows the newURL has been applied to the data-attribute
```

```html
<select data-ajax--url="/live_search/Customer/id/name/name" class="form-control kt-select2 kt-live_search form-control-md" id="consignments_customername" data-placeholder="All">
  <option>option 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch data value , split, change with new value and join.

```js
let str = $('#consignments_customername').data('ajax--url');
str = str.split('/');
let id = str[3];
str[3] = "newID";


let newurl = str.join('/')
$('#consignments_customername').attr('data-ajax--url', newurl);
console.log(newurl);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-ajax--url="/live_search/Customer/id/name/name" class="form-control kt-select2 kt-live_search form-control-md" id="consignments_customername" data-placeholder="All">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will join and also give an answer. Method `replace()`.

```js
let data_ajax_url = $('#consignments_customername');

data_ajax_url.attr('data-ajax--url', data_ajax_url.attr('data-ajax--url').replace(/\id/, 'id_new'));

console.log(data_ajax_url.attr('data-ajax--url'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-ajax--url="/live_search/Customer/id/name/name" class="form-control kt-select2 kt-live_search form-control-md" id="consignments_customername" data-placeholder="All">
  <option></option>
</select>
```